# Image brightness manipulation in canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, canvas

I want to change to brightness of the image. I have a big project and below is a minimal reproducible example.

I have added this line to detect an ID in a object and assign a brightness to the image property.

```
 for (let j = 0; j < imageOverlay.length ; j++) {
    if (id == imageOverlay[j]) {
        image.style.filter = "brightness(200%)";
    }
}
```

When console logging the `image` it displays:

```
<img src="https://assets.coingecko…ravencoin.png?1548386057" style="filter: brightness(200%);">
```

I have no clue why the brightness is not displayed on the image.

I'm using html canvas and would like to do this with plain javascript.

Thanks for helping me, the full code can be found below.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var circles = [];

//Init Start
let circle = new Circle();
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/3412/large/ravencoin.png?1548386057";
var id = "id";

//Image overlay for brigther images
var imageOverlay = ["id"];

for (let j = 0; j < imageOverlay.length ; j++) {
    //Check for id
    if (id == imageOverlay[j]) {
        console.log("FOUND ID: " + imageOverlay[j]);
        //Change brightness
        image.style.filter = "brightness(200%)";
        console.log(image);
    }
}

circle.init({
   image, c, id,
});

circles.push(circle);

//draw image
animate();

function Circle() {
    //Give var
    this.diameter = 100;
    this.id = id;
    this.image = image;
    this.c = null;

    //Draw circle on canvas
    this.draw = function () {

    //Image overlay for brigther images
    for (let j = 0; j < imageOverlay.length ; j++) {
        if (this.id == imageOverlay[j]) {
            this.c.filter = "brightness(300%)";
        }
    }



        this.c.beginPath();
        this.c.drawImage(this.image, (100 - this.diameter / 2), (100 - this.diameter / 2), this.diameter, this.diameter);
        this.c.closePath();
    };

    //Init circle properties
    this.init = function (options) {
        Object.keys(options).forEach((key) => {
            this[key] = options[key];
        })
    }
}

//Draw / Animate image
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    circles[0].draw();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<canvas></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can change the brightness of an image with the style, but that does not change the original, and the original is what the canvas uses to draw.

What you need to do is apply that brightness filter to the context.
Before you call the:
 `this.c.drawImage(this.image`
you just set the filter:
`this.c.filter = "brightness(200%)";`

Below is an animated example

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = document.querySelector('img');

bright=0
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
  b=Math.sin(bright/60)*100 + 100
  c.filter = "brightness("+b+"%)";
  c.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
  
  b += 100
  c.filter = "brightness("+b+"%)";
  c.drawImage(image, 50, 0, 100, 100);
  
  b += 100
  c.filter = "brightness("+b+"%)";
  c.drawImage(image, 100, 0, 100, 100);
  bright++
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas height="100" width="200"></canvas>
<img src="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/3412/large/ravencoin.png?1548386057" height="100" width="100" style="filter:brightness(90%);">
```

Comment: Hi Helder, thank you for the answer. I have hunderds of images from an external source. This was just to demonstrate a reproducable demo. Because of that reason I cant use a <img> tag. Do you know another way to filter the images or change the original picutures? Thanks, I would like to hear back from you.

Comment: @AttackTheWar I changed my answer a bit adding more description

Comment: Thank @helder! I have updated the code and placed the loop inside the this.draw function. It updates the image corretly! Now every time the images has been drawn the filter is applied. Is there another way to do this so it is more efficient? ex apply the filter before being drawn?

Comment: @AttackTheWar I'm not sure what that loop is doing there...  all you need is to call the  `this.c.filter...` before `this.c.drawImage...`