# How do I manipulate an image and then save the results?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, canvas, vuejs3

I want to make a simple web photo editor. I want to change the brightness, contrast, etc.

Here is my code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { getFromDB } from './db.ts'

const data=ref(getFromDB())
const img=ref<HTMLImageElement>()
const onLighter=()=>img.value.style['filter']='brightness(120%)';
const onDarker=()=>img.value.style['filter']='brightness(80%)';
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ src===data }}</h1>
  <button @click="onLighter">lighter</button>
  <button @click="onDarker">darker</button>
  <img ref="img" :src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+data"/>
</template>
```

We read the data from the "simulated" database (just a function returning image as base64-data).

Changing the brightness and contrast on the screen is very easy.

But how do we save the manipulated image data after changing it?

[playground...](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you are not actually manipulating the image. You are styling the image using CSS filters. Image has not changed, try saving image after applying the filters; Still the original image.

To do image manipulation you could use Canvas instead, as it allows some pretty neat image manipulation.

Mozilla has a great tutorial I would recommend reading; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial

But I'll give you a basic example where we can lighten and darken the image, that we load from "DB".

And also how we can get the manipulated data from our canvas so we can update our "DB" with it.

*Unfortunately, I am not well traversed in Vue, so I will keep it simple in "Vanilla Java Script". But the general principals should work the same.*

```js
// Setup our Canvas
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Load our image into the Canvas
const img = new Image();
img.src = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${getImageFromDb()}`;
img.onload = () =>
{
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  const imgX = canvas.width/2 - img.width/2;
  const imgY = canvas.height/2 - img.height/2;
  
  // Draw the original image into the Canvas
  context.drawImage(img, imgX, imgY);
}

function brightness(multiplier) {
  const imgX = canvas.width/2 - img.width/2;
  const imgY = canvas.height/2 - img.height/2;
  const imageData = context.getImageData(imgX, imgY, img.width, img.height);
  const dataArray = imageData.data; // Get the raw pixel data in array (red, green, blue, aplha)
  
  // Loop over each set of pixels
  for(let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i += 4)
  {
    // Get the red, green and blue pixels
    var red = dataArray[i];
    var green = dataArray[i + 1];
    var blue = dataArray[i + 2];
    
    // Change the value with our multiplier
    dataArray[i] = multiplier * red;
    dataArray[i + 1] = multiplier * green;
    dataArray[i + 2] = multiplier * blue;
  }
  
  // Update the Canvas data
  context.putImageData(imageData, imgX, imgY);
};

function save() {
  // canvas.toDataURL() gives us the data url, but we only want the base64-string to save
  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL().replace('data:', '').replace(/^.+,/, '');
  console.log(dataURL); // This value could be save to db
}

function getImageFromDb() {
  return "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";
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button onClick="brightness(1.5)">Lighter</button>
<button onClick="brightness(0.5)">Darker</button>
<button onClick="save()">Save</button>
```

Comment: Could you also tell us about the contrast? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76160588/15924692

Comment: Sorry. It looks like the basic concept is there. However, changing contrast is a lot harder. Looks like it does "change contrast" but you get burnt image since the effect is so strong I would say. One must first understand the concept of contrast, and it is harder than one would expect. In the simplest form it is just to make all dark pixels darker and light pixels lighter... but that usually does not give desired results. And if you add color to that its a science. :-D

Answer (score -2):

А slightly different approach was pointed out here [https://stackoverflow.com...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155135/image-brightness-manipulation-in-canvas-with-javascript)
Made an example using both options. Both work.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { getFromDB } from './db.ts'
import { brightness } from './utils.ts'

const img=ref<HTMLImageElement>()
const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
const context: CanvasRenderingContext2D=canvas.getContext("2d");
const data=ref('data:image/jpeg;base64,'+getFromDB())
let imgX = 0
let imgY = 0

const onSave=()=>{
  data.value=canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 5) 
}
  
const onLoad=()=>{
  canvas.width = img.value.width;
  canvas.height = img.value.height;
  imgX = canvas.width/2 - img.value.width/2;
  imgY = canvas.height/2 - img.value.height/2;  
  context.drawImage(img.value, imgX, imgY);
}

const lighter1=()=>{
  brightness(img.value, 1.5, canvas, context)
}

const lighter2=()=>{
  context.filter = "brightness(150%)";
  context.drawImage(img.value, imgX, imgY);
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="lighter1">lighter1</button>
  <button @click="lighter2">lighter2</button>
  <img ref="img" :src="data" @load="onLoad"/>
  <button @click="onSave">save</button>
</template>
```

[playground...](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Considering that there is no ready algorithm for changing the contrast in the public domain yet. For uniformity of approaches to change both brightness and contrast, I like the filter approach better.

Comment: The linked answer does not resolve the question of how to save the manipulated data. Just displays a different way of manipulating using Canvas. What best approach is for manipulating the image, can vary. 

My answer actually does showcase how to manipulate pixels, as a photo editor would do, or close to it. It is a lot more powerful than applying filters in my opinion.

But yeah, do not answer your own question with a link to another question, or as a combination. Comment is enough to ask this.