# The right algorithm for changing the contrast of an image

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vuejs3

I am creating a primitive photo editor.
I found on the Internet an algorithm for changing the contrast of an image.
I made a test project.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import FileLoader from './components/FileLoader.vue'

const img=ref<HTMLImageElement>()
const canvas=ref<HTMLCanvasElement>()
let context:CanvasRenderingContext2D | null = null
const src = ref('')

const onLoad = (value: string) => src.value = value

const onImageLoad=()=>{
  if (!canvas.value || !img.value) throw new Error()
  canvas.value.width = img.value.width;
  canvas.value.height = img.value.height; 
  context=canvas.value.getContext("2d");
  if (!context) throw new Error()
  context.drawImage(img.value, 0, 0);  
}

const contrastFilter=ref(100)

const applyContrast = (data: Uint8ClampedArray, contrast: number) => {
  const truncateColor = (value: number) => value < 0 ? 0: value > 255.0 ? 255.0 : value
  const factor = (259.0 * (contrast + 255.0)) / (255.0 * (259.0 - contrast))
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    data[i] = truncateColor(factor * (data[i] - 128.0) + 128.0)
    data[i + 1] = truncateColor(factor * (data[i + 1] - 128.0) + 128.0)
    data[i + 2] = truncateColor(factor * (data[i + 2] - 128.0) + 128.0)
  }
}

const setContrast=(contrast: number)=>{
  if (!canvas.value || !img.value || !context) throw new Error()
  const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.value.width, img.value.height);
  if (!imageData) throw new Error()
  applyContrast(imageData.data, contrast)
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  contrastFilter.value=contrast
}
</script>

<template>
  <FileLoader @onLoad="onLoad" />
  <hr/>
  <img ref="img" :src="src" @load="onImageLoad" :style="'filter:contrast('+contrastFilter+'%)'"/>
  <canvas ref="canvas"/>
  <hr/>
  <button @click="setContrast(100)">100</button>
  <button @click="setContrast(101)">101</button>
  <button @click="setContrast(105)">105</button>
  <button @click="setContrast(130)">130</button>
</template>
```

[Vue SFC Playground...](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

The image on the left shows the css-filter applied, on the right the algorithm in action.
If you try to change the contrast, you can see that the algorithm does not work correctly. I would be grateful if you could tell me where I am wrong.